# REST API Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I would like to use the following in my Controller:

```
[Route("api/{controller}/{action}")]
```

instead of using `RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(...)`. The problem is that it says that Route is not an attribute class. I have included the following libraries:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Routing;
using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
```

I have `Microsoft.Aspnet.Mvc 5.2.3` and `Web API 2.2`. I tried to follow this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx and added

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
       routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
       routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

but it says that `IgnoreRoute` and `MapMvcAttributeRoutes` don't exists.. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Both `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web.Http` namespace have attribute `Route`. Try remove reference to `System.Web.Mvc` or explicit namespace of `RouteAttribute`

Comment: As specified above try putting [System.Web.HttpRoute("api/{controller}/{action}")] to explicitly reference it by the correct namespace.

Answer (score 1):

In web api you can use the attribute RoutePrefix that works as a prefix for all the controllers actions

You can do something like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/apps")]
public class ApplicationsController : ApiController{

        [Route("get/{id}"))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult>GetApplications(int id)
```

Comment: yes i do have also routeprefix.. but again it says that its not an attribute class..

Comment: if you are using the webapi routing you should add in your webapiconfig file, under the register method  the call

        'config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();'

Comment: which call do you mean?

Comment: take a look here 

[link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

this works with web api 2, you have to consider is if you are using an mvc controller you have to use different packages, try the other solution suggested

Answer (score 0):

I've just created a quick test project using Mvc 5.2.2. In your controller you only need

```
 using System.Web.Mvc;
```

For the RouteAttribute and in the `RouteConfig` only

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
```

Having `using System.Web.Http;` and `using AttributeRouting.Web.Http;` is prob just confusing the situation (no idea what library AttributeRouting.Web.Http is from or is this a typo?). Your WebApi config should be done in a different class. Also make sure you have System.Web.Mvc.dll referenced, just in case

Comment: Yes maybe the problem is that I have a namespace WebForms and I am not wure whether I should add using System.. inside the namespace or outside... If I add using System.Web.Mvc; inside the namespace everything is messed up...

Comment: Messed up how? You can add 'using' inside or outside a namespace. But what has the namespace WebForms got to do with the code above? Should you have posted more code? The question refers to the RouteConfig class you WILL need using System.Web.Mvc and using System.Web.Routing in that file inside or outside the namespace declaration